# Why cv::Mat object can be output directly with std::cout?

Tags: c++, opencv

In opencv official tutorial([Creating a Mat object explicitly](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html)), there is code like this:

```
    Mat M(2,2, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255));
    cout << "M = " << endl << " " << M << endl << endl;
```

But when I look into the source code of Mat class, I can't find why Mat object can be output with `cout <<` since there isn't overload function like `operator <<` or even something like `ostream &`?

Comment: The stream output operators are not defined in the class itself.  It would be a separate function somewhere like: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Mat&);` -- note if you're finding it difficult to locate this function, then try compiling without optimizations, run your program with the debugger attached and step into the function.

Comment: Thanks a million! I really appreciate it. That's the approach I'm sruggling to find for days!

Comment: Here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp#L87